Open a file with Neovim on WSL through Alacritty after double-clicking that file in Windows 11
I am using the following setup:

Windows 11
WSL (Ubuntu 22.04)
Neovim installed and configured on WSL (I prefer using the WSL version of Neovim over the Windows version)
Alacritty installed on Windows

I want to improve my workflow so that when I double-click a file (.txt, .json, etc...) in Windows, it triggers the following actions:

Opens Alacritty
Launches WSL within Alacritty
Starts Neovim (from WSL) and opens the file I just double-clicked

How can I configure my laptop to achieve this behavior (with "alacritty.toml", Windows configuration, etc...) ?
